# What could cause network lag to increase when the number of connection goes below 3

Tags: linux, networking, gaming, lag

This is a Linux server, running Minetest 5.1. When 3 or more people are connected, lag is usually some fraction of a second. But if only 1 or 2 people are connected, lag can jump to 3 seconds or higher.

This seems to be the inverse of what I would expect.

This isn't FPS, I'm talking about network lag. Any ideas?

Comment: Sounds like there is a buffer on hard- or software level that is only flushed when it is full. The more users the faster the buffer is full and then it is transmitted.

Comment: So a smaller buffer would/could be better? Well, that's something to look into. Thanks.

Comment: Well, that would be a workaround. But the real solution is to flush the buffer periodically. Keep in mind that this buffer may be located in any of the involved systems, including all system i the network path.